# How to play a simple audio file (Java)?

Tags: java, audio

The question basically explains itself. I want to take an audio file (I can use any format really) and have Java output sound from it when called on.

Comment: Have you considered Googling this?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is an efficient way to have sound, whether you want to infinitely loop music or just want a sound to play once. I'm posting because it took me a long time to figure out which method of sound actually worked for my purposes. **This method can only use AIFC, AIFF, AU, SND, and WAVE files. I find that the WAVE files, .wav, are easier because there are plenty of mp3(or whatever file you want to convert) to .wav converters online.**

Imports:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
```

Sound method:

```
public void sound() {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("NameOfFile.wav"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
        // If you want the sound to loop infinitely, then put: clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); 
        // If you want to stop the sound, then use clip.stop();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope that this helps.